# API Resource for non APIs

Tags: laravel

I'm aware when building an API, you can use API Resources to modify data from the database, to present it to the front end.

But, with a standard/Inertia application, I return data from the model, but I find that I would like a middle layer to transform the data before it's passed back to JS and rendered.

What can I utilize to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use same with inertia also inside your controller method.

```
$data= DataResource::collection(Data::all());
    
return Inertia::render('VueComponent', compact('data'));
```